# c++ 2D vector push_back error in code

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

I had my program working with a single vector and decided to use a 2D vector to represent multiple hands (one dimensional vector vPlayerHand1 plus one dimensional vector vPlayerHand2 plus ...).  I can't figure out how to populate the vector.  I am using Visual Studio C++ 2010 which does not seem to fully implement C++11 and reports parsing errors in the IDE for code that is provided as answers to similar questions in this forum. In the outline below Card is a class.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<Card>> vPlayerHand;

vPlayerHand.push_back(vShoe.back());  /* fails with parsing error No instance of 
                                         overloaded function... */
vPlayerHand[0].push_back(vShoe.back());  /* builds okay then error Debug Assertion
                                            Failed... vector subscript out of range */
```

I am missing something on the correct use of the push_back function with a 2D vector (vector of vectors) I understand the first reference is to the row. and when I populate with push_back it should just do the first row.

Here is more complete code:

Edited at line 29... code runs correctly as given
Re-edited at line 32a as per solution by @RSahu runs correctly. Commented out line 29

```
1  # include <iostream>
2  # include <vector>
3  # include <algorithm>
4  # include <ctime> 
5  # include "Card.h"  //Defines Card as having Suit, Rank and functions GetSuit()   GetRank()
6
7  std::vector<Card> vShoe;                  //Card Shoe vector holds 1-8 decks
8  std::vector<Card> vDeck;                  //Deck vector holds 52 cards of Card class
9  std::vector<std::vector<Card>> vPlayerHand; // Player Hands 0-original, 1-split1, n-splitn
10 std::vector<Card> vDealerHand;
11
12 void CreateDeck();       //Populates Deck with 52 Cards 
13 void CreateShoe(int);   //Populates Show with Decks*n number of Decks
14 void ShuffleShoe();      // uses random_shuffle
15 
16 int main() {
17 
18 int iDeckCount = 2;
19 const int NumPlayers = 1;
20 srand(time(0)); 
21 
22 
23 CreaateDeck();
24 CreateShoe(iDeckCount);
25 ShuffleShoe();
26 
27 // Following line gives parsing error
28 // vPlayerHand = std::vector<std::vector<Card>> (5, std::vector<std::vector<Card>>(12));

    // added this line and now runs as expected
    /* removed this line in favor of line 32a as per @RSahu  
29 vPlayerHand.resize(2);  // need only initial size for 2 elements
    */

30 for (int i=0; i<=NumPlayers; i++) {
31      // I believe this is where dimension error comes vPlayerHand[0].push_back
32      // I tried vPlayerHand.push_back(vShoe.back()) but get parsing error "No instance of overloaded function.."

        // This line added as per R Sahu.  compiles and runs correctly
32a     vPlayerHand.push_back(std::vector<Card>());
33      vPlayerHand[0].push_back(vShoe.back()); //Top card in Shoe (last card in vector) is dealt to Player
34      vShoe.pop_back();                       //Top card in Shoe is removed (destroyed) from vector Shoe
35      vDealerHand.push_back(vShoe.back());    //Top card in Shoe (last card in vector) is dealt to Dealer
36      vShoe.pop_back();                       //Top card in Shoe is removed (destroyed) from vector Shoe
37      }
38 
39 /* Show Results
40  std::cout << "\n---------------------------------\n" ;
41  std::cout << "   Players Hand" << std::endl;
42  std::cout << vPlayerHand[0][0].GetRank() << "," << vPlayerHand[0][0].GetSuit() << " ";
43  std::cout << vPlayerHand[0][1].GetRank() << "," << vPlayerHand[0][1].GetSuit() << std::endl;
44 */
45 }
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: When posting code, remove the line numbers, so one can easily copy/paste/compile/run

Comment: I thought that the numbers would help.  Not clear from reading other posts whether numbers are beneficial or detrimental.  In future I will leave the numbers off because adding them was a pain.

Comment: @NipperDJ don't post line numbers, but indciate which line corresponds to which number that appears in any error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `vPlayerHand` as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Card>> vPlayerHand;
```

When you use `vPlayerHand.push_back(arg)`, `arg` has to be of type `std::vector<Card>` or convertible to `std::vector<Card>`. An argument of type `Card` cannot be used as an argument to that function. That's what you are trying when you use

```
vPlayerHand.push_back(vShoe.back())
```

What you need is:

```
vPlayerHand.push_back(std::vector<Card>());
vPlayerHand.back().push_back(vShoe.back());
vShoe.pop_back();
vPlayerHand.back().push_back(vShoe.back());
vShoe.pop_back();
```

Comment: @NipperDJ, but `vShoe.back()` is not. The return type of `vShoe.back()` is `Card`.

Comment: in my code vShoe is a vector of type Card (str::vector<Card> vShoe;) So I don't quite follow the first line you provided... it seems redundant.  But I did find solution by adding line: vPlayerHand.resize(2);   I edited my code and it now runs as shown.  Nonetheless I will vote you an answer.  I will test with the code you supplied.  I have much to learn about c++.  Thank you.

Comment: Ohhh ... I get it now.  Thank you so much.  I was populating with the push_back but using wrong argument as you pointed out.  by using resize I create the elements of type Card and then the push_back as i used it was okay.

Comment: @NipperDJ, the first line adds an empty `vector<Card>` to `vPlayerHand`. If `vPlayerHand` is empty, `vPlayerHand.back().push_back(vShoe.back());` will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: You are the best!! I have read dozens of posts related to this and several pages of reference material and never understood what you just made clear to me.  Thank you for your talents and clear explanation.

Comment: @NipperDJ, I am happy that I was able to help.